# Birational Kawamata-Viehweg vanishing for positive characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

My question is the following:

> Let $k$ be a algebraically closed field of positive characteristic, $(X,\Delta),(X',\Delta')$ $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial strongly $F$-regular pairs, and $f:X'\to X$ a proper birational morphism. Is that true that $R^if_*\mathcal{O}_{X'}(L)=0$ for $i>0$ if $L$ is a Cartier divisor on $X'$ such that $L-(K_{X'}+\Delta')$ is $f$-nef?

I believe it is true. Indeed, there is an analog of such a proposition in https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.08343. Of course, over positive characteristic, the Kawamata-Viehweg vanishing is false in general, but it seems that the birational Kawamata-Viehweg vanishing is true for strongly $F$-regular pairs. How to prove or disprove it? Are there results about such proposition?